# concatenate two fields in drop down list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a model class

```
namespace myapp.Models
{
    public class SubjectModels 
    {
        [Key]
        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int SubjectType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MinLength(5)]
        public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here, `SubjectType = 1 for Optional and SubjectType = 2 for Compulsory`

Now in another class I have to create a drop down for this class,

```
namespace myapp.Models
{
    public class SelectionModels 
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int SelectionId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MinLength(5)]
        public string SelectionDate { get; set; }
        
        [ForeignKey("SubjectId")]
        public SubjectModels Subject { get; set; } 

        public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I genereted controller and create.cshtml via scaffolding, my create controller method:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.SubjectId = new SelectList(db.Subjects, "SubjectId", "SubjectName");            
    return View();
}
```

But I have to create a drop down concatenating the fields "*SubjectName*" and "*SubjectType*". Also, display for *SubjectType* should be Optional and Compulsory not integer.

for example,

```
"Optional - ResearchMethodology"
"Compulsory - BioChemistry"
```

How shall I do this? I googled but could not found suitable solutions. Please help!!!

Answer (score 1):

I would create an extra property in the `SubjectModels` class.

```
class SubjectModels
{
    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public int SubjectType { get; set; }
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }

    public string SubjectNameAndType
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0} - {1}", SubjectName, SubjectType);
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the Controller you can use that property to fill the `SelectList`

```
var list = new List<SubjectModels>()
{
    new SubjectModels()
    {
        SubjectType = 1,
        SubjectName = "Name 1"
    },
    new SubjectModels()
    {
        SubjectType = 2,
        SubjectName = "Name 2"
    }
};

ViewBag.SubjectId = new SelectList(list, "SubjectId", "SubjectNameAndType");
```

Now you will see the correct values in the DropDownList.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MyValue, (SelectList)ViewBag.SubjectId, "Select...")
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. but my subject list is dynamic. It seems you are filling the values from the controller method only... Also I don't want to display integer value in `SubjectType` Please read the complete question. Please suggest on this too.

Comment: The static list is just for this example. There is no difference for the `SubjectNameAndType` property. And you can edit the code in the property to suit your needs.

Comment: How can I change the `SubjectType` value to "Optional" , "Compulsory" for 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: `SubjectType == 1 ? "Optional" : "Compulsory";`